# Issue running a script from init.rc on device boot up

Tags: android, service, boot

I am trying to run a shell script, which copies a file to a specific location, on phone power up and I added the following to my *init.rc* file:

```
service test_copy /system/bin/sh /system/bin/test_copy.sh  
    class pre-zygote_services  
    oneshot  
    user system  
    group system
```

When the service name `(test_copy)` is same as the script name, `test_copy` in this case, it doesn't execute the script but if I change the service name to a different one, like `start_test_copy`, it works. I am just eager to know the reason on why when service name is same as script name it doesn't work or am I wrong?

Comment: Hi...I observed something similar. Did you figure out the reason?

Answer (score 2):

Try this one in your init.rc:

```
service test_copy /system/bin/test_copy.sh
user root
oneshot
```

Your test_copy.sh script must begin with:

```
#!/system/bin/sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Always make sure use a different name for your service which Android init recommends.

Also, you can make your test_copy.sh  into the executable by defining the Android Make file.